# Replace image with div if image doesn't exists

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

*how correctly reflect image if it exists & replace it with `div` otherwise?*

```
// I don't know how to get `imageExists` without making cross-origin
(imageExists) ? (<img class="avatar-img" src={this.state.imageDataUrl}/>) : 
                     (<div class="avatar-img no-avatar"><span>{shortcut}</span></div>)
```

Of course I can do separate `XmlHttpRequest` but that's lots of unnecessary code + cross-origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onerror) event to catch all images that failed to load and replace them with the `<div>` you want:

```
$('img').on('error', function() { 
    $(this).replaceWith('<div class="avatar-img no-avatar"><span>{shortcut}</span></div>');
});
```